# Postgres 11 json manipulation. This is generated from the db tables

Tags: postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    json_object_agg(lc.name, lo.data) as data
FROM
    categories AS lc
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        select lo.uuid, json_agg(json_build_object('name', lo.name, 'uuid', lo.uuid))::jsonb as data from table AS lo WHERE lo.join_uuid = lc.uuid
        GROUP BY lo.uuid
    ) lo on true
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS cl ON cl.table_option_uuid = lo.uuid 
WHERE
    cl.VALID = TRUE 
    AND cl.customers_uuid = 'f36fd4ed-3968-4da9-9f58-2a7f5b4a3477'
```

This query produces a result of:

```json
{
   "key1":[
      {
         "name":"Test",
         "uuid":"af3d9101-df86-4513-95c5-163d3cd4c30a"
      }
   ],
   "key1":[
      {
         "name":"Other",
         "uuid":"8a479f8a-bbb4-41fc-879f-bf8f49055f71"
      }
   ],
   "key2":[
      {
         "name":"Test2",
         "uuid":"c3792372-284c-452b-afe7-c43ca5366056"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need key1 aggregated to a single array:

```json
{
   "key1":[
      {
         "name":"Test",
         "uuid":"af3d9101-df86-4513-95c5-163d3cd4c30a"
      },
      {
         "name":"Other",
         "uuid":"8a479f8a-bbb4-41fc-879f-bf8f49055f71"
      }
   ],
   "key2":[
      {
         "name":"Test2",
         "uuid":"c3792372-284c-452b-afe7-c43ca5366056"
      }
   ]
}
```

The keys are generated by the database, so I know what the keys are, however there is over 40.
I have tried `json_object_agg`, `json_build_object`, and `json_agg`.

The `jsonb_set()` function doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.

To create the tables:

```
create table lc (uuid uuid, name varchar); 
create table lo (name varchar, uuid uuid, join_uuid uuid);
create table cl (customers_uuid uuid, table_option_uud uuid);
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that [`json_object_agg` could produce invalid JSON with duplicate keys](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0261ee7d4a5539fedf05aa528d493852)

Comment: Could you share your table definitions and maybe some sample data so that we could run the above query ourselves? It's a bit unclear to me where the duplicate keys are coming from. Does `categories` (`lc`) have multiple rows with the same names? What about `table` (`lo`), does it even have multiple names for the same uuid - was `json_agg` your attempt at creating the array?

Comment: Yeah, let me get that together and i'll post in a couple hours.

Comment: Added the table definitions, i'll get you data in a moment. I am AFK for a while. lo is unique, how ever lc is not. LC has many LO and LO can be named the same thing IF it belongs to a different LC.

Comment: I think all you need to do is move the `LEFT JOIN table2 AS cl` inside your lateral subquery

Comment: @Bergi: just use `jsonb_object_agg()` :)

Comment: @Bergi moving it to inside the lateral query did not work...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name using jsonb_object_agg does not work. It only selects one of the options for key1

Comment: @dev: yes, because you can't have duplicate keys in a JSON structure and JSONB removes them, you will need to first aggregate the value per key - then convert that to a JSON value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it took another change but i got it. I needed to remove the lo.uuid and group by, as well as use jsonb_object_agg... it worked, thank you for the direction.